# Laravel 5, pagination and ordering a list by a relationship count

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

Am trying to sort a query by a linked table count and cannot figure out how to use Laravel pagination; below is my query that is passed to the view

I think the Laravel 5 paginator method has been moved?

```
    $companies = Company::with('locations')->get()->sortBy(function($count)
    {
        return $count->locations->where('status', '=', 'Active')->count();
    }, null, true);
```

Because the get and sortby functions are called I cannot apply pagination (error below)

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::pagination()

Maybe there is a alternative way to do sorting by the count of a hasMany relationship - in this case "locations". (side question; I do not know how to make the above work with a hasManyThrough relationship).

The model relationships are shown below

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
}

public function equipment()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Equipment', 'App\Location');
}
```

Using something like the below gives an undefined "make" method?

```
return Paginator::make($companies->all(), $companies->getTotal(), $companies->getPerPage())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 paginate collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233667/laravel-4-paginate-collection)

Comment: This is laravel 5; I think the pagination has changed significantly since 4?

Comment: I think the fundamental dilemma is the same, though. Once you have a collection, the db query is done, so at that point the best you can do is chunk the full result. So you need (apparently) a custom pagination object on the db query object at the point where its relevant and apparently not predefined (the relationship filter, I would presume?) But in all fairness, I've never touched laravel, I just think its dandy and like reading questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my edited answer, the sort By command and pagination can indeed work together and the following should work for you, of course you may need to adjust the columns in the scopes join statement.

Add this function to your Company class.

```
    public function scopeLocationCount($query){
    return $query->join('locations','locations.company_id','=','companies.id')
            ->selectRaw('companies.*, count(locations.id) as count')->where('locations.status','=','active')->groupBy('companies.id');
}
```

And then you can make the call to the paginate method like so.

```
$companies= (Company::with('locations')->locationCount()->orderBy('count')->paginate(30));
```

And then after you write your foreach loop to display the details you need to render the paginator like so `{!! $companies->render() !!}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do as you suggest; each page will be sorted by the count - I want the whole set to be sorted by the count.

Comment: Then move the paginate call to the end after your sortBy.

Comment: I made changes to my answer, luckily I was going to have to tackle the same issue myself, and I found that this works for me.

Comment: The problem with the above is that it will now only return companies that have a relation (and has the where condition) and sort by the count - I want the result to also include entries with zero counts (and still only "count"/"sort" the locations that are active) @Azeame