# Laravel eloquent add extra models to hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a `user` Model and each user has multiple `licenses`. There are 2 default licenses that apply to all users that are not in the `licenses` table and they need to be created on the fly using certain data contained in the `User` model.

How can I create 2 licenses each time I'm getting a user's licenses and add it to the output of `licenses()`?

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function licenses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\License', 'user_id', 'id')->where('deleted', '=', '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote with no feedback, very helpful

Comment: Where are these additional licenses store?

Comment: Why not add them to the licence table when creating the user? You can do this in the `EventProvider`.

Comment: @max.lanin they are not stored anyway per say, but the `User` model has some properties which relate to these default licenses.

Comment: @Jerodev I'm working on a existing system and I want to try and do it without modifying the system in any way

Comment: Problem is that if you want to use laravel's relation functionality, such as eager loading, or populate model with relations, this relation method should return `Relation` instance. So there are two ways, I think: use @Jerodev comment and add these licenses on creating event, or make another method that will populate all licenses via relation method and add 2 default on top.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extra function in the model where you call the licenses and add the extra licenses.

Remember to test all places where you use this function so no strange stuff will happen.

```
<?php

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    // HasMany function
    public function _licenses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\License', 'user_id', 'id')->where('deleted', '=', '0');
    }

    // New licenses function
    public function licenses() 
    {
        // Get licenses from database
        $licenses = $this->_licenses;

        // Add  other lisences
        $licenses = $licenses->add(new License([ "user_id" => $this->id, "name" => "foo" ]));
        $licenses = $licenses->add(new License([ "user_id" => $this->id, "name" => "bar" ]));

        // Return the new collection
        return $licenses
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did actually try something similar because I thought `$this->hasMany` returned a collection but apparently it doesn't. I just tried your answer and I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::add()`

Comment: Oh, my bad, you have to call `$this->_licenses` without the `()`, this will return the collection.

Comment: Oh cool good to know how to return the collection. Unfortunately that throws another error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: Could you show the exact code you are using? Can you put it on pastebin or something?

Comment: Sure, here's the User model - http://laravel.io/bin/d9LaP#53
And here's the Controller - http://laravel.io/bin/Kky38

Comment: It's probably because I call the `->with('licenses')` and it's supposed to return the Query Builder but it now returns a collection. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Try using `$users->licenses()` to get the licenses and then you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233667/laravel-4-paginate-collection) to use pagination on a laravel collection